# Execute object code in mmap-ed memory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple JIT in python involves writing machine code to mmap-ed memory and then executing it.

Following the instructions in this [blog post](https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2013/04/03/basic-jit/), the object code for the doubling function

```
int multby2(int a) { return 2*a; }
```

is (on my macOS El Capitan machine)

```
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   7:   8b 7d fc                mov    edi,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   a:   c1 e7 01                shl    edi,0x1
   d:   89 f8                   mov    eax,edi
   f:   5d                      pop    rbp
  10:   c3                      ret
```

Writing this as a Python 3 bytes object:

```
MULT_BY_TWO_OBJ = b''.join([
    b'\x55',          # push   rbp
    b'\x48\x89\xe5',  # mov    rbp,rsp
    b'\x89\x7d\xfc',  # mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
    b'\x8b\x7d\xfc',  # mov    edi,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
    b'\xc1\xe7\x01',  # shl    edi,0x1
    b'\x89\xf8',      # mov    eax,edi
    b'\x5d',          # pop    rbp
    b'\xc3',          # ret
    ])
```

My program for writing this machine code to an mmap-ed buffer and then executing is as follows:

```
import mmap
import ctypes

mm_buf = mmap.mmap(
    -1, len(MULT_BY_TWO_OBJ),
    flags=mmap.MAP_ANONYMOUS | mmap.MAP_PRIVATE,
    prot=mmap.PROT_WRITE | mmap.PROT_EXEC)

mm_buf.write(MULT_BY_TWO_OBJ)

prototype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)
mm_buf_address = ctypes.c_int.from_buffer(mm_buf)
double_func = prototype(mm_buf_address.value)

print(double_func(ctypes.c_int(1)))

mm_buf.close()
```

Running this program results in a segmentation fault:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Is it possible to execute mmap-ed machine code like this in Python? Is there a better approach in Python than using `mmap` and `ctypes`?

Comment: Seems to me like you'd need to include `PROT_READ` in the `prot` flags, otherwise how can the processor execute the instructions? Can't test this myself, since I'm on Windows where `mmap` thinks different.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's necessary--see the example in the blog post I linked, which is where I got the permissions from. I also gave it a shot (adding ` | mmap.PROT_READ` to the `prot` argument of `mmap`) and I still got a Segmentation fault :(